# Entity Mapping for fields in MS CRM 2011

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm try to using entity mapping for fields in CRM solution.
I create custom  opportunity form with e-mail and requiered potential customer fields.
In Potential customer field you can choose an account from system, or create new.
In account form I have e-mail field too, and I want map this field on e-mail field in opportunity.

I did everything in this article:
http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/vincent/12-03-02/Use_Entity_Mapping_to_implement_the_Clone_function_in_Dynamics_CRM_2011.aspx

And if I create a new account or choose existing in opportunity form, e-mail field not filling.

I read this answers:
[CRM 2011 - Using contact data on Case form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521503/crm-2011-using-contact-data-on-case-form)
[In Dynamic CRM fill in the field automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311436/in-dynamic-crm-fill-in-the-field-automatically)
and know, that I can use js or workflow. But I out of the box feature in CRM not working for me now. I googling all day, and found peoples with the same problem, but not found solution.

It's look like bug in CRM. I use CRM 2011 in local virtual machine without rollup (because they didn't install and asked to reinstall crm server).
Maybe anyone know about this strange  behavior of entity mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapped values will be applied when you choose Create Related from the ribbon.
This feature is more for pre population of data when you are creating a related record. Future changes to the value of the mapped attribute on the parent record will not update the values on the related child records.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand this.
Also, I did relation for fields between forms with javascript.